Is there a way to locally (i.e. on my machine) check my cabal project dependencies against whatever environment Hackage provides?
The foreword is the same as my previous question

Some time ago I worked on this project, and I experimented a bit with package candidates.
Then, yesterday, I uploaded the real package on hackage. However, it fails to build

except that I tried a few more times, trying to adjust the version bound over and over, but always getting an error on some other dependency. Below are the logs from older to recent:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xnobar-0.0.0.1/reports/1
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xnobar-0.0.0.1/reports/2
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xnobar-0.0.0.1/reports/3
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xnobar-0.0.0.1/reports/4
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xnobar-0.0.0.1/reports/5

The loop of

uploading new version bounds,

waiting for the build to finish/fail,

if step 2 failed,
3.1 look the error and trying to work out what dependecy bounds I need to change,
3.2 upload new bound
3.3 go to step 1,

hurray!


is very time consuming and frustrating.
Is there a better way?
I'm clearly excluding the way "make your local environment identically to Hackage's".
Ideally, I'd just want something like cabal check --against-hackage-at-this-very-moment I can run on my command line.
I'm clearly not the only one to feel the frustration.

I'm clearly excluding the way "make your local environment identically to Hackage's". Why? That seems a reasonable way to ensure that what you compile works in hackages environment as well.

I agree this developer experience should be improved. I can only offer a band-aid:
Most of the issues concern packages that are locked into specific GHC versions. You can avoid those issues by simply using the same GHC version as Hackage uses. Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to get that version of GHC automatically. Even so, if you just make sure it builds with the oldest stable version (see the GHC status page), then Hackage will likely be able to build it too.
